# How to hide a form after submit button is pressed

Tags: php, forms, hide

I have created a simple program in php. I get the user to enter a string and then the reverse of the string is printed out. My question is how would hide the form after the submit button is pressed? my code that i have written is below

```
<?php
//TASK 16 ENTER A STRING AND REVERSE IT

$str = $_POST['usersString'];

$len = strlen($str);

for($i=($len-1); $i>=0; $i--){
    echo $str[$i];
}




?>

<form action="task16.php" method="POST">
Enter a string to reverse! <input type="text" name="usersString" />
<input type="submit" value="enter" />
</form>
```

Comment: WHere is code to hide?

You have to use JQuery to hide your form when submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//TASK 16 ENTER A STRING AND REVERSE IT

if( isset( $_POST['usersString'] ) && !empty( $_POST['usersString'] ) )
{
    $str = $_POST['usersString'];
    $len = strlen($str);
    for($i=($len-1); $i>=0; $i--){
        echo $str[$i];
    }
} else {
?>
<form action="task16.php" method="POST">
Enter a string to reverse! <input type="text" name="usersString" />
<input type="submit" value="enter" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I assumed that your current file name is task16.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//TASK 16 ENTER A STRING AND REVERSE IT

$str = $_POST['usersString'];

$len = strlen($str);

for($i=($len-1); $i>=0; $i--){
    echo $str[$i];
}


if (empty($_POST)) {

?>

<form action="task16.php" method="POST">
Enter a string to reverse! <input type="text" name="usersString" />
<input type="submit" value="enter" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this page as ***task.php***

```
<?php
//TASK 16 ENTER A STRING AND REVERSE IT
$str = $_POST['usersString'];
$len = strlen($str);
for($i=($len-1); $i>=0; $i--){
    echo $str[$i];}
?>
```

Make this as a html form page name it whatever you want

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="task.php" method="POST">
    Enter a string to reverse! <input type="text" name="usersString" />
    <input type="submit" value="enter" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So now when your user enters the value on the form page the action will take place on the task.php and it will display only what you want and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST['usersString'])){

//TASK 16 ENTER A STRING AND REVERSE IT

$str = $_POST['usersString'];

$len = strlen($str);

for($i=($len-1); $i>=0; $i--){
    echo $str[$i];
}

} elseif (!isset($_POST['usersString'])){
?>

<form action="task16.php" method="POST">
Enter a string to reverse! <input type="text" name="usersString" />
<input type="submit" value="enter" />
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```